# How can I call stored procedure result into view model asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedures

How can I call the stored procedure  into view model

```
SqlParameter paruserID = new SqlParameter("@UserID", userId);
 SqlParameter paryear = new SqlParameter("@LogYear", lockyear);
 SqlParameter parmonth = new SqlParameter("@LogMonth", lockmonth);
 var result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<AttendanceViewModel>("EmpProcedure", paruserID ,paryear ,parmonth
```

Comment: Hi @systemthreep, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Database.SqlQuery` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) is not provided in EF Core. If you'd like to execute a stored procedure, you can try to use the `FromSqlRaw` extension method, like below.

```
var result = _db.Attendance.FromSqlRaw("EXEC EmpProcedure @UserID, @LogYear, @LogMonth", parameters)
    .ToList()
    .Select(u => new AttendanceViewModel
    {
        UserID = u.UserID,
        LogYear = u.LogYear,
        LogMonth = u.LogMonth
        //other fields
        //...
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

For more information about executing Raw SQL Queries, you can check following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Besides, the `DbContext.Database` property provides an API that allows us to perform ADO.NET operations directly, you can also use following code snippet to execute your stored procedure.

```
using (var command = _db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.CommandText = "EmpProcedure";

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", userId));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LogYear", lockyear));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LogMonth", lockmonth));

    _db.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // ...
        // code logic here
        // do something based on your actual requirement
    }
}
```

For more information about leveraging ADO.NET via the Context.Database property, please check:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#leveraging-ado.net-via-the-context.database-property